# Why does Python allow function calls with wrong number of arguments?

Tags: python, arguments

Python is my first dynamic language. I recently coded a function call incorrectly supplying a wrong number of arguments. This failed with an exception at the time that function was called. I expected that even in a dynamic language, this kind of error can be detected when the source file is parsed.

I understand that the **type** of actual arguments is not known until the function is called, because the same variable may contain values of any type at different times. But the **number** of arguments is known as soon as the source file is parsed. It is not going to change while the program is running.

#### So that this is not a philosophical question

To keep this in scope of Stack Overflow, let me phrase the question like this. Is there some feature, that Python offers, that requires it to delay checking the number of arguments in a function call until the code actually executes?

Comment: What if the name refers to a different function entirely at runtime?

Comment: well, as a counterargument, count of arguments for invoking `f(*args)` won't be known during parsing phase.

Comment: @Rogalski but on the other hand, no number of positional arguments to that would raise the `TypeError`!

Comment: It should be noted that, in type theory, the type of values includes the number of arguments, in the case of functions.

Comment: How does Python know which function you're going to call until you actually try to call it? It's not like functions in Python have names. (This is not sarcasm)

Comment: The identity of the function being called can be changed while the program is running.

Comment: @immibis: Well, no. They do have names. They're not particularly *attached* to those names, though. A function defined as `def foo(): whatever` has `foo.__name__ == 'foo'`, but that won't stop you from doing `foo = some_other_function` or `bar = foo`.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Python cannot know up-front what object you'll end up calling, because being dynamic, you can *swap out the function object*. At any time. And each of these objects can have a different number of arguments.

Here is an extreme example:

```
import random

def foo(): pass
def bar(arg1): pass
def baz(arg1, arg2): pass

the_function = random.choice([foo, bar, baz])
print(the_function())
```

The above code has a 2 in 3 chance of raising an exception. But Python cannot know a-priori if that'll be the case or not!

And I haven't even started with dynamic module imports, dynamic function generation, other callable objects (any object with a `__call__` method can be called), or catch-all arguments (`*args` and `**kwargs`).

But to make this extra clear, you state in your question:

> It is not going to change while the program is running.

This is not the case, not in Python, once the module is loaded you can delete, add or replace any object in the module namespace, including function objects.

Comment: I've seen function tables before, so it might not be _quite_ so evil. Oh wait, the functions in the table don't use `*` arguments.... and this is _Python_ so.... yep, pretty extreme.

Comment: [It's a t-shirt now.](http://www.customink.com/designs/randfunc/dxy0-00ad-n539/hotlink?pc=HL-142344&utm_campaign=hotlink_201601&utm_source=hotlink&utm_medium=email&utm_content=viewbutton&cm_mmc=hotlink-_-5-_-Body_txt-_-viewbutton) (If couldn't figure out how to add attribution. If you want it, tell me, and I can probably figure it out.)

Comment: @PyRulez: My t-shirt with a [Unicorn-shaped copy of the regex-parsing post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261514/100297) uses a URL. You could just add `https://stackoverflow.com/a/34567789` and be done with it.

Comment: @PyRulez: but this is just a dispatch list, really. The *point* is to illustrate that you can use functions as objects, and you can't know up-front which one is called. Otherwise it is a [reasonably common technique](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/182093/why-store-a-function-inside-a-python-dictionary/182095#182095).

Comment: Maybe for helping the user to it's original problem: detecting the mistake before the code running, the use of static verification tool could be mentioned.

Answer (score 35):

The number of arguments being passed is known, but not the function which is actually called. See this example:

```python
def foo():
    print("I take no arguments.")

def bar():
    print("I call foo")
    foo()
```

This might seem obvious, but let us put these into a file called "fubar.py". Now, in an interactive Python session, do this:

```python
>>> import fubar
>>> fubar.foo()
I take no arguments.
>>> fubar.bar()
I call foo
I take no arguments.
```

That was obvious. Now for the fun part. We’ll define a function which requires a non-zero amount of arguments:

```python
>>> def notfoo(a):
...    print("I take arguments!")
...
```

Now we do something which is called *[monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch)*. We can in fact *replace* the function `foo` in the `fubar` module:

```python
>>> fubar.foo = notfoo
```

Now, when we call `bar`, a `TypeError` will be raised; the name `foo` now refers to the function we defined above instead of the original function formerly-known-as-`foo`.

```python
>>> fubar.bar()
I call foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/horazont/tmp/fubar.py", line 6, in bar
    foo()
TypeError: notfoo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

So even in a situation like this, where it might seem very obvious that the called function `foo` takes no arguments, Python can only know that it is actually the `foo` function which is being called when it executes that source line.

This is a property of Python which makes it powerful, but it also causes some of its slowness. In fact, [making modules read-only to improve performance has been discussed](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2014-May/027870.html) on the python-ideas mailinglist some time ago, but it didn't gain any real support.